# Use hoist-non-react-statics with withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-router-v4

How to use `hoist-non-react-statics` with `withRouter`

I am adding a static method in `Feedback` component.

This was my original code.  I am trying to use new changes in Context API (react v 16.6)

```
Feedback.contextType = AppContext;

export default withRouter( Feedback );
```

This works fine, but I am getting the below warning in console.

> Warning: withRouter(Feedback): Function components do not support
>   contextType.

So to fix the warning I used the method proposed by Dan [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14061). Its also mentioned in react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over)

So I have this code now which is not working.

Imported the `hoist-non-react-statics`

```
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import hoistNonReactStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics';
```

And exported the component like this

```
Feedback.contextType = AppContext;
hoistNonReactStatics( Feedback, withRouter(Feedback) );

export default Feedback;
```

but for some reason router info (history, match etc) is not populated in `props`

Any pointers why its not working?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. What's the connection between hoistNonReactStatics and props? Are you saying that props work ok without hoistNonReactStatics but don't work with hoistNonReactStatics ?

Comment: @estus I have updated the question with more details...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this warning but provided a fix. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second snippet isn't supposed to work because `withRouter(Feedback)` isn't exported from the module.

As [linked issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14061#issuecomment-435443838) explains, the problem was that `hoist-non-react-statics` wasn't treated `contextType` static property correctly. This has been fixed in latest `hoist-non-react-statics` version. Since `react-router` uses older `hoist-non-react-statics` version as a dependency, this could be fixed in-place:

```
Feedback.contextType = AppContext;

export default Object.assign(withRouter(Feedback), { contextType: undefined });
```

Or:

```
Feedback.contextType = AppContext;

const FeedbackWithRouter = withRouter(Feedback);
delete FeedbackWithRouter.contextType;
export default FeedbackWithRouter;
```

Or:

```
export default withRouter(Feedback);

Feedback.contextType = AppContext;
```

Comment: `contentType` is added in version 3.1.0 https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics/pull/62

Comment: That's correct. While react-router's dependency is v2. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. As I mentioned, I wasn't able to replicate it. If the problem was that `withRouter(Feedback)` inherited contextType from wrapped component then a fix would solve it.

Comment: Warning is gone, but this method has a disadvantage as mentioned in React docs, we need to know the static method in prior. I am looking for a solution with `hoist-non-react-statics`

Comment: It seems that you misunderstand the role of hoist-non-react-statics here. It's already applied by withRouter. Applying it again won't do any good. All you can do is to negate its effects. You don't necessarily need to know whether contextType is there or not. It should just go away in enhanced component. You can use your own helper, `let withRouter(...args) => { let Comp = ReactRouter.withRouter(...args); delete Comp.contextType; return Comp }` Or fork react-router, update it hoist-non-react-statics@^3.1 and possibly do a PR.

Answer (score 2):

I had that warning with and without 'hoist-non-react-statics' using, and it has disappeared when I had updated react-router-dom to the latest version (5.0.0)